# How to divide digit on a condition and to unite through a divider?

Tags: bash, split, grep

There is a variable which contains `20190105221953.ogg`,
Want it turns to `"2019-01-05 19:59:53"`

Tried to apply regex with needed quantity of numbers
`grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{4}'`
But It's not working.

Comment: Where did the `19:59:50` come from :O?

Comment: You can always use substring: `"${var:0:4}-${var:4:2}..."`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, PesaThe!

```
var=`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`.ogg
echo ${var:0:4}-${var:4:2}-${var:6:2} ${var:8:2}:${var:10:2}:${var:12:2}
```

Comment: Consider maybe shorter: `var=$(date +"%F %T"); echo "${var} >> ${var//[-: ]}.ogg"`.

Comment: `var=`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`.ogg` - this only tested dynamic filename, filename `20190105221953.ogg` does not change.

Comment: I see. Thought you might be creating a filename and printing the date in a readable format.

Answer (score 1):

You can try converting your string to datetime with `date` command:

`date -d "${var:0:8} ${var:8:2}:${var:10:2}:${var:12:2}" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`

This may help for flexible output of the date by changing `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`

Answer (score 0):

Though it seems awkward to use `sed`... :

```
echo $var
#=> 20190105221953.ogg

echo $var|sed -E 's/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2}).*/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6/'
#=> 2019-01-05 22:19:53
```